# How to serve images in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I import my hashed image urls:

**Component:**

```
import basicSmartLogo from "../../assets/img/smart_logo_basic.png"

@Component({
  selector: "home",  // <home></home>
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent {

  basicSmartLogo = basicSmartLogo;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="{{basicSmartLogo}}">
```

This seems to work on in SPA builds but in universal the  urls are very mangled. How do I use hashed resource urls in angular universal?

Comment: Did you check that your Universal urls are being served absolute(ly)? https://angular.io/guide/universal#absolute-http-urls

Comment: How can I make sure that they are absolute?  I'm going to set public path in my webpack config like this:
  output: {
    publicPath: ASSET_PATH
  },

Comment: @HunterFrazier How do I get the name of my hashed image without it getting mangled so that I can prepend my CDN path to it and make it absolute?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue as follows.

1. Create a `configuration.production` object in the `server` object in `angular.json` as described in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10417#issuecomment-390491021.
2. Add `"outputHashing": "media"` to the `configuration.production` object
3. Execute `ng run {PROJECT_NAME}:server:production` instead of `ng run {PROJECT_NAME}:server` to build server-side code.

Comment: Thank you. For me, who have used ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [name],  file Replacements was already configured and only "outputHashing": "media" was missing. I have not changed my command line witch stay npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr